# Should I use "will" or "going to" or Present continuous to describe an upcoming future arrangement that will be held continuously for some time?

Tags: future-tense

I am writing a formal email to a teacher, the sentence I am sending:

"By the start of next week, we are going to launch weekly online sessions to provide support for our students"

I want to express that starting from next week, we will have online sessions that will be repeated every week till the end of the semester but I am not quite sure about the usage of "are going to" in the sentence.

Am I expressing the the overall sentence correctly?

Comment: "Starting Monday of next week, we will be launching weekly online sessions to provide support for our students"  is how I would phrase it.  Your phrasing is fine and legal, but is just a touch passive to my ear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want in this instance is to use the [future continuous](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/future-continuous-tense/). The future continuous tense indicates that an action will take place in the future, and will continue to do so. It is formed using *will* + *be* + *present participle*.

Additionally, the expression "by the start of next week" effectively causes the reader to start counting from now, until the start of next week. It would be better to use an expression which causes the reader to start counting from the time next week starts and onward.

> "*Starting next week*, we **will be launching** weekly online
>   sessions to provide support for our students"